# How to use Jasmine spies on an object created inside another method?

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine, spy

Given the following code snippet, how would you create a [Jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html) `spyOn` test to confirm that `doSomething` gets called when you run `MyFunction`?

```
function MyFunction() {
    var foo = new MyCoolObject();
    foo.doSomething();
};
```

Here's what my test looks like. Unfortunately, I get an error when the `spyOn` call is evaluated:

```
describe("MyFunction", function () {
    it("calls doSomething", function () {

        spyOn(MyCoolObject, "doSomething");
        MyFunction();
        expect(MyCoolObject.doSomething).toHaveBeenCalled();

    });
});
```

Jasmine doesn't appear to recognize the `doSomething` method at that point. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you call `new MyCoolObject()` you invoke the `MyCoolObject` function and get a new object with the related prototype. This means that when you `spyOn(MyCoolObject, "doSomething")` you're not setting up a spy on the object returned by the `new` call, but on a possible `doSomething` function on the `MyCoolObject` function itself.

You should be able to do something like:

```
it("calls doSomething", function() {
  var originalConstructor = MyCoolObject,
      spiedObj;
  spyOn(window, 'MyCoolObject').and.callFake(function() {
    spiedObj = new originalConstructor();
    spyOn(spiedObj, 'doSomething');
    return spiedObj;
  });
  MyFunction();
  expect(spiedObj.doSomething).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Answer (score 25):

Alternatively, as Gregg hinted, we could work with 'prototype'. That is, instead of spying on MyCoolObject directly, we can spy on MyCoolObject.prototype.

```
describe("MyFunction", function () {
    it("calls doSomething", function () {
        spyOn(MyCoolObject.prototype, "doSomething");
        MyFunction();
        expect(MyCoolObject.prototype.doSomething).toHaveBeenCalled();

    });
});
```

Comment: Seven years late to the game here but this helped me out today so thank you.